# maven-war-plugin creates an uncompressed file that thinks its compressed

Tags: maven, plugins, war

I have a binary file, a public key in this case, extension .spec.

When I deploy my war, or just extract the war file, the key file is corrupted. It looks like something has attempted to uncompress it. The original uncompressed file size is 162 bytes and after I extract it from the war it is 280 bytes.

If I rename the file to .png this doesnt happen!!

Comment: Do you use resource filtering in your Maven project? The size difference could be caused by filtering the file and replacing some values in there.

Comment: It's a binary file. And no, no filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nwinkler I didnt know what resource filtering was when you asked. Turns out I do use it!

This item is duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483279/maven-war-plugin-increases-size-of-my-resource/16484296)