# maven-war-plugin increases size of my resource

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a file (/src/main/resources/myfile.library) which is gzipped xml. When the plugin copies the file to the target directory it is almost twice the size. I can no longer open the file, no idea what it is or whats happened.

Any ideas? How can I stop the plugin playing with my resources?

Comment: Sounds like you do resource filtering? Can you post the full pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct @khmarbaise. As usual I found this out after posting the question!

And here's the fix. Add a filter=false resource for binary eg.

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```